# How do I make my zsh prompt look like sh/bash end with $ instead of %?

Tags: command-prompt, zsh

Can anyone show how to modify the following zsh prompt environment var assignment to make its emitted string end with `$` (followed by a space), instead of `%`?

```
export PROMPT='%F{111}%m:%F{2}%~ %#%f '
```

macOS Catalina changed the default shell to zsh, and I saw an article that encouraged a switch. I assumed backward compatibility but prompt logic changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export PROMPT='%F{111}%m:%F{2}%~ $%f '
```

For more options on zsh prompt string customization - http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Login-information

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer: use `%(!.#.$)`

---

### Long answer:

The portion of your prompt string that's generating the `%` is `%#` -- which generates `#` if the shell is a privileged (root) shell, and `%` otherwise.

If you still want that general class of behavior, just with `$` instead of `%`, you can do `%(!.#.$)` in place of `%#`.  This is a conditional, with three parts (each separated by `.`): `!` checks to see if the shell is privileged, the `#` is the expansion value if the check comes back true, and the `$` is the expansion value if it's false.

A demonstration session (in a shell with a starting prompt of simply `%`  (`PROMPT='%% '`)):

```
% PROMPT=': %#; '          ;: # the default %# (unwanted %, just to show it)
: %; sudo -s               ;: # prompt is % now -- until we switch to root
: #; exit                  ;: # prompt is # now -- exit to return to user
: %; PROMPT=': %(!.#.$); ' ;: # set new prompt string with conditional for #/$
: $; sudo -s               ;: # prompt is $ now -- what we wanted
: #; exit                  ;: # prompt is # for root shells, still
: $;                       ;: # back to user shell, prompt back to $
```

Folding this in to your prior settings, we have:

```
export PROMPT='%F{111}%m:%F{2}%~ %(!.#.$)%f '
```

Should do the trick!

---

*(As a random side-note, I'm using `;` and the builtin `:` command to effect comments where they might not otherwise be allowed -- and in particular, to treat the prompt itself as a comment, so it can be copy/pasted along with a command to re-run the command -- at the expense of some noise in your shell where you paste it.  Also, the above example assumes sudo has been run recently enough, and/or is otherwise configured, to not require a password -- of course, if it did, this would all still work, it would just be extra noise in the example.)*